# Unity "Unable to find the Android SDK manager tool" (path already set)

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk

If I start my Unity Project I get this message:

```
Unable to find the Android SDK manager tool.  Required Android packages (extra-google-m2repository) can not be installed.  Android SDK path not set.  Set the Android SDK property using the Unity "Edit > Preferences > External Tools" menu option on Windows or the "Unity > Preferences > External Tools" menu option on OSX. Alternatively, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

But I installed the complete sdk and also set the path via Preferences. What Im doing wrong?
My sdk is in the same folder as UNITY.

Answer (score 0):

just check if the android sdk folder was configured correctly in `Edit->Preference->External Tools`

[image]

Comment: Set the path to "D:/UNITY/sdk" there are the following files: https://imgur.com/a/dnMuB

Comment: @UngerGames that seem the correct folder, what's your problem with that?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qI7bK I think thats all fine there but I still get this error :/

Comment: Be aware of the `slash/back-slashes` they make difference as I can remember :D

Comment: Doesnt work either. Maybe because Im using a old sdkmanager?

Comment: there is indeed a [mis-match bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-build-fails-when-the-latest-android-sdk-tools-25-dot-3-1-version-is-used) of unity version and android sdk version problem, I have replaced my `tools` folder as the link I give suggested. haven't been following that issue since, and don't know if they have fixed that, maybe you are facing same problem

Comment: Thanks Ill try that later.

Comment: Doesnt work :( I found out that all other projects work. I get this notification only in 1 Project.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue. It all started to when i tried to install a unitypackage which includes a GooglePlayServiceResolver. And only happened in one project, while other projects don't complain about 'missing sdk'.

I had it solved by not using the GooglePlayServicesResolver included by the unitypackage.
This is what i did :
 1. Remove all files that was installed by the package, including the resolver.
 2. Download and install latest resolver.
 3. Re-import the package, but this time without the resolver since i already had the latest.
My resolver ran automatically and resolved dependencies without complaining about missing Android SDK anymore.